# Can heat be generated when water rubs off rock?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

I have been wondering lately if heat can be generated when water flows over rock. Let's talk on a planetary scale. If an ocean planet had a rock seabed and a solid rock core and the ocean was 40km deep would heat be generated as the water moved around the planet?

Also,(Just a side question) if vortex's in the water occurred would any heat be generated as the water spun around really fast in one place?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would heat be generated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would generate heat.  Determining how significant the heat would be is a whole other beast that I'm not going to get into.

But yes, essentially fluids have friction losses due to effects of viscosity.

This generates heat just like rubbing your hand over a surface would generate heat from the friction.

I assume the internal viscous effects of a vortex would heat it up as well.